# SQL count avg mess. per user_id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to count the avg number of messages sent by distinct users_id. I have the messages under the table "comments" , and the distinct users_id under the table "user". They join under the use of another table "tickets" this way:

```sql
left outer join tickets t on c.ticket_id = t.ticket_id
left outer  join "users" u on u.user_id  = t.requester
```

I'm not too sure where to start from either.

```sql
select user_id,
count avg (distinct c.ticket_id)
from "comments" c
group by ticket_id
left outer join tickets t on c.ticket_id = t.ticket_id
left outer  join "users" u on u.user_id  = t.requester
where t.created_at between '2022-10-01' and '2022-10-31'
```

Comment: Average comments per ticket? Can a ticket have comments from more than one user? Mean, median, or mode average?

Answer (score 0):

This might give you the result you want. The Common Table Expression counts the comments per ticket, then we select the average of the counts per ticket grouped by user.

```
with UserTicketCount (user_id, ticket_id, theCount) as
(
      select u.user_id
           , t.ticket_id
           , count(c.comment_id) as theCount
        from users u
   left join tickets t
          on t.requester = u.user_id
   left join comments c
          on c.ticket_id = t.ticket_id
   group by u.user_id, t.ticket_id
)
select user_id
     , avg(theCount) as AvgCommentPerTicket
  from UserTicketCount
group by user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

We'll start from the original query in the question:

```
select user_id,
count avg (distinct c.ticket_id)
from "comments" c
group by ticket_id
left outer join tickets t on c.ticket_id = t.ticket_id
left outer  join "users" u on u.user_id  = t.requester
where t.created_at between '2022-10-01' and '2022-10-31'
```

Given this, there are a number of things we need to change:

- `join` and `where` must be listed before `group by`
- This is not the correct format for SQL Server date literals. For date-only values, [you should skip the `-` separators and just have `yyyyMMdd`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166772/5469).
- If `created_at` is a full datetime, you probably need an exclusive upper boundary for November 1, rather than inclusive for October 31. If this is not true, normal naming conventions for date-only values are to use names like "created_on" instead of "created_at", and using an exclusive upper bound is still a good thing to do.
- You can't select for `user_id` if your `GROUP BY` is for `ticket_id`. In this case, probably `user_id` is correct for both.
- You can't use `count` and `avg()` at the same time.

Put it all together and you end up with this:

```
SELECT AVG(MessageCount)
FROM (
    SELECT user_id,
        count(distinct c.comment_id) as MessageCount
    FROM "comments" c
    LEFT JOIN tickets t on c.ticket_id = t.ticket_id
    LEFT JOIN "users" u on u.user_id  = t.requester
    WHERE t.created_at >= '20221001' AND t.created_at < '20221101'
    GROUP BY u.user_id
) t
```

Note I had to guess at the primary key for the `comments` table.

Finally, it's strange to me that a ticket is needed to imply the user associated with a comment. Surely more than one person can be on a ticket?